# How to set Cache-Control of a URL embedded within a special non-http URL (Python/Django)

Tags: python, html, django, url, httpresponse

**BACKGROUND:**

In the `form_valid` method of a Django `view` of mine, I am constructing a URL via **string concatenation**. Imagine the said URL to be http://example.com/uuid, where `uuid` is a POST variable passed to this `form_valid` method.

In this method, I will next be constructing a custom `HttpResponse` object that will lead to a **non-http** url, being `nonhttp_url = "sms:"+phonenumber+"?body="+body`. `body` contains some text and the url I formed earlier via string concatenation (e.g. 'go to this url: `[url]`'). `phonenumber` is any legit mobile number.

The `HttpResponse` object thus constructed is actually an HTML trick that is used to open the native SMS app of a phone and pre-fill it with a phone number and SMS body. It's common usage is `<a href="sms:phonenumber?body="+body">Send SMS</a>`. I'm essentially calling the same thing, but from inside the `form_valid` method of my Django view.

**QUESTION:**

How do I ensure that the URL I formed via str concatenation above and passed into the `body` section of the non-http url has `Cache-Control` set to `no-cache`? In fact, I also want `no-store` and `must-revalidate`. Similarly, I also need `Pragma` set to `no-cache`, `Expires` set to `0` and `Vary` set to `*`.

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
class UserPhoneNumberView(FormView):
    form_class = UserPhoneNumberForm
    template_name = "get_user_phonenumber.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        phonenumber = self.request.POST.get("mobile_number")
        unique = self.request.POST.get("unique")
        url = "http://example.com/"+unique
        response = HttpResponse("", status=302)
        body = "See this url: "+url
        nonhttp_url = "sms:"+phonenumber+"?body="+body
        response['Location'] = nonhttp_url
        return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think that you'd do it just as you would for an HTTP URL? You'd set the headers by [using the response as a dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields), just like you are for the `Location` header. In this case, adding lines like: `response['Vary'] = '*'`.

As a convenience, you could use [`add_never_cache_headers()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.cache.add_never_cache_headers) to add the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers.

Here's an example:

```
from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers

class UserPhoneNumberView(FormView):
    form_class = UserPhoneNumberForm
    template_name = "get_user_phonenumber.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        phonenumber = self.request.POST.get("mobile_number")
        unique = self.request.POST.get("unique")
        url = "http://example.com/"+unique
        response = HttpResponse("", status=302)
        body = "See this url: "+url
        nonhttp_url = "sms:"+phonenumber+"?body="+body
        response['Location'] = nonhttp_url

        # This will add the proper Cache-Control and Expires
        add_never_cache_headers(response)

        # Now just add the 'Vary' header
        response['Vary'] = '*'
        return response
```

Comment: Yea I know what you mean. But I'm thinking when we do this, do we not add `no-cache` et al *solely* to the `nonhttp url` we constructed? For instance, with the code you wrote, the `url` itself (defined as `url = "http://example.com/"+unique`) hasn't had its `Cache-Control` set, right? We've only set the `Cache-Control` of the nonhttp url it was a part of, no? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, `Cache-Control` is set on HTTP responses, not on URLs.  If your desire is to set headers on a response from the `"http://example.com/"+unique` url, you'd have to make sure that URL returned a response with those headers. There's no way for you to specify headers on responses other than the current one. If you also control the URL that you're sending, that should be easy to do.

Comment: I see what you mean.